# better way to count defined elements in sparse array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Consider the following typescript:

```
const myArray: Array<string> = new Array();
myArray[5] = 'hello';
myArray[7] = 'world';

const len = myArray.length;
let totalLen = 0;
myArray.forEach( arr => totalLen++);
console.log('Total elements in the array: ' + len.toString(10));
console.log('Total defined elements in the array: ' + totalLen.toString(10));
```

Output:

```
Total elements in the array: 8
Total defined elements in the array: 2
```

I need to insert data into an array at arbitrary indexes, which creates undefined array elements.  I then need to check the total number of defined elements in the array.  .length includes the undefined elements, but .forEach only iterates over defined elements.

It seems like there should be a better way to do this, but I just don't know the right methods.

Comment: @str found the answer I couldn't find (google-fu was bad today).  The previous answer also ended up using .forEach

.filter works like .forEach does.  I just thought there might be something built-in by now that didn't require iterating over the whole array like they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array, and then find the length, like so:

`myArray.filter(i => i !== undefined).length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example following `myArray.filter(v => v !== undefined).length`. There will be sure more solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arrLng = myArray.filter(item=>item !== undefined).length 
console.log('Total elements in the array: ' + myArray.length );
console.log('Total defined elements in the array: ' + arrLng);
```

Comment: This will remove all "falsy" elements like "false" or "0" which can cause unwanted side effects.

Comment: Filter wont remove elements from myArray. What are u talking about?

Comment: I didn't mean it gets removed from the array. I meant they will not be present in the returned value (`arrLng`). Which can cause side effects.

Comment: Oh, sure... Fixed it up. Thanks